# Header Tag in XML using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Right now I am getting this as an XML output from my JAXB Marshaller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><create></create>
```

But I want my root element as:

```
<create xmlns="http://ws.abc.com" xmlns:doc="http://ws.abc.com">
```

Do I need to modify this using parsers, Or is there any annotation available.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set the following property on the `Marshaller` to remove the header:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used a [Transformer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) in the past. You'd want something like the following sample code:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StreamResult transformedDoc = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(content); // Where content is a org.w3c.dom.Document object.

transformer.transform(source, transformedDoc);
```

So maybe do your marshalling and then process. Not sure if this is the best approach but it would work.